# Accessing elements of OpenCV CV_8UC1 cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a cv::Mat of type CV_8UC1 (8-bit single channel image) and I would like to access elements using the `at<>` operator as follows: `image.at<char>(row, column)`. However, when casting to `int`: `(int) image.at<char>(row, column)`, some values become negative, e.g., 255 becomes -1.

This might be a stupid question, but I can't tell why this happens and what would be a better way to convert the entries to `int`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to specify that the elements are **unsigned char**, between 0 and 255 , otherwise they will be char (signed), from -128 to 127. The casting will be this way:

```
(int) image.at<uchar>(row,column);
```

Answer (score 6):

In the matrix type CV_8 **UC** 1 stands for Unsigned Char.

So, you have to write

```
image.at<unsigned char>(row, column)
```

Comment: Actually `U` stands for unsigned, but that `C` stands for _channel_, meaning the variable type is 8 bits, unsigned, and single channel. So, for example, `CV_16SC2` is a 2-channel 16-bit (per channel) signed data type (which has nothing to do with a `char`, although there is a `C` there).